# How do I add observer to UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, observer-pattern, uicontrolevents

I want be signaled when user will touch button (UIControlEventTouchUpInside). How do I add observer to UIButton?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the documentation of [UIControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
[myButton addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(touch:) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This method works for anything that inherits from `UIControl` (including but not limited to `UIButtons` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
// add target and action
[myButton addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

where the target is the class where the UIButton is added or implemented. If you set nil for addTarget, the action will go through the responder chain until a responder is found that responds to the buttonClicked: selector. buttonClicked: selector is implemented like the following:

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
 // do stuff here
}
```